# Can someone please explain the differences between Cocos2d-Swift, SpriteBuilder, Xcode and CocoaPods?

Tags: ios

I'm completely confused and I don't know where to start asking questions. I tried googling, but the terminology is confusing and I'm not sure what either of these things do (except for Xcode). Can someone explain like I'm 5?
I'm on the cocos2d-swift website and after reading the getting started section it says "From this point onwards, using SpriteBuilder is optional.". I don't know what they mean by that.

How do each of these correlate with each other?

Also, how is an API Documentation Browser and Code Snippet Manager useful to an everyday iOS Developer?

Answer (score 3):

**cocos2d-swift** is a framework that enables you to build things like sprite-based games quickly.

**SpriteBuilder** is a tool that helps you build your own multilayered sprites (images and animations grouped into a single package -- i.e. Mario, a Goomba, a Fireflower fireball, etc.).

**Xcode** is a developer environment in which you write your source code, compile, distribute, and test.

**CocoaPods** is a tool that fetches and manages framework/SDK dependancies.

You would use **CocoaPods** to fetch the **cocos2d-swift** framework so that you could build a sprite-based game in **Xcode** using sprites you generated in **SpriteBuilder**.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what Cocos2d is, but swift is the latest programming language by Apple for both OS X and iOS development.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_(programming_language)

SpriteBuilder is a framework used to create games for iOS very quick. Think of it as a game engine.

http://www.spritebuilder.com/about

Xcode is the IDE (integrated development environment) that you use when writing native OS X and iOS applications. It's awesome!

CocoaPods is a way to load in third-party libraries and frameworks without having to manually install them on your own. It also makes it very easy to keep the frameworks up-to-date. Pods also allows your project to be more portable as it's much easier to install an application with multiple dependancies via Pods.

http://cocoapods.org

A documentation browser is good if you want to have access to documentation while offline. However, I almost always use Google to find what I'm looking for regardless of what technology I'm working on. Google is just the best way to search.

Finally, I'd start off with this book. I read the first edition years ago, and made things very easy for me to understand.

http://www.bignerdranch.com/we-write/ios-programming.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some basics:

XCode (A Program)- Most of your iOS development will happen here.  Coding, creating the app etc.

Think of an SDK as a suite of commands or tools you can use-API's (API - Application programming interface)

Cocoas2d (An SDK) - Game engine.  A software development kit for creating games.  you would pull this library of code and tools into xcode to use it.

SpriteBuilder (An SDK) - Suite of tools for building games.  Just like Cocoas, you would pull this into xCode to make use of it as you code.

CocoaPods - A tool for linking/loading SDK's into XCode and easily updating them.

Moral of the story: XCode is the software you will use for everything.  Everything else are just additional libraries of code you can pull in.